# How to remove email icon from Android Studio emulation

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I get rid of the email icon on the bottom of the phone? It is on all of them and it shouldn't be there.[image]

Comment: It is a Floating Action Button, it could be either in a XML layout or added programmically - I think, and I could be wrong, that all new 'blank activity' templates in Android Studio 1.4 are like this now where a floating action button is already coded by default.

Comment: You should use a smaller image in your question next time instead of a full resolution image, just so everyone doesn't have to scroll all the way down to see the icon and can get to the answer quicker.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Go to activity_main.xml and delete this portion:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

And then go to MainActivity.java and delete this portion

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
```

That's it. You should now see that the icon disappeared.

Comment: `activity_main.xml` is in `res/layout`

Answer (score 10):

I guess you are looking for it in `content_main.xml` and that is why you don't see it. Check `activity_main.xml` and delete it from there.

Answer (score 5):

This is what your looking to remove

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"   android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

its not in the activity_main.xml its inside the app_bar_main.xml

Answer (score 2):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Delete this code from app_bar_main.xml

Comment: Please post only if you have additional information or value ad than other answers. Other answers already specified this part

Answer (score 0):

Look for `src` attribute in your layout file of the `Activity` and change it.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_email"
            app:elevation="4dp"
            ... />
```

Comment: I dont have that but it is still there