# I can not remove the default pink FloatingActionButton in a Navigation Drawer activity

Tags: android, floating-action-button

So, I can not for the life of me figure out why I can't remove the default FAB that comes with the navigation drawer activity. I've done [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33286804), I've tried clicking the button in both the Design view for `activity_main.xml` and `content_main.xml`, but I can't select it, so I can't delete it either.
Does anyone know if this button is somehow baked in in the NavDrawer activity, or is there just something I'm missing here?

I'm using AS 1.5.1.

Comment: Did you try to delete this<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's in app_bar_main.xml in layout folder.

Comment: You sir are a hero. Exactly what was going on here. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Switch to `text` view in your XML and dry delete the `FloatingActionButton` view. Also search for `FloatingActionButton` in the activity's Java file and delete it from there. It is in the `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the same from XML file which has the floating action bar defined. If you are not sure, go to main activity class where your navigation drawer is declared. Ctrl+mouse primary button on the id of floating action bar(with android studio) this will directly take you the XML file where its defined. Comment that part alone. Come back to activity class and comment code related to floating action bar. Done. You are all set to go for further customisation.

Answer (score 0):

for not getting it back again..
When you choose to create a new Activity, always choose Empty Activity, instead of Basic Activity..

Comment: It must be a comment