# Remove mail icon from activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I remove the mail icon on the bottom right (see the screenshot)? It has been automatically created and I can't select it in Design view in Android Studio

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZJc5.png)

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205146/how-to-remove-email-icon-from-android-studio-emulation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove email icon from Android Studio emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205146/how-to-remove-email-icon-from-android-studio-emulation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your `activity.xml`, click on it then press `delete`. I has  id `fab` meaning `Floating Action Button`

Comment: Android studio created two layouts, one for the activity and one for the "content" of the activity. I was looking in the activity, and the FAB was in the "content" layout.

Answer (score 2):

In your activity layout file look for this tag

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>
```

and remove this.